# What is the normal font used by LaTeX in the amspset class?

Tags: fonts

I am using the `amspset` package, which can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/mattmastin/teaching/grsc-7700/latex-templates). I am using

```
\documentclass[reqno, 11pt, letterpaper]{amspset}
\usepackage{fullpage, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
```

What is the right command to change the font? I like the 11pt size I have chosen. I just want to change it to the font a normal LaTeX document uses. I don't know the command for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default font is "palatino", as you can see in `ampset.cls`, which contains the following lines:

```
% use palatino fonts
\DeclareOption{palatino}{%
    \amspset@palatinotrue%
}

% use compuer modern fonts
\DeclareOption{cm}{%
    \amspset@palatinofalse%
}

...

% pass remaining options to article class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

%%% EXECUTION OF OPTIONS --------------------------------------------------
%% default to:
% including header,
% loading mathpazo package for palatino fonts,
% boxing problem statements
\ExecuteOptions{header,palatino,boxed}

\ProcessOptions
```

If you want to use the default "Computer Modern", you have to load the package with the option `cm`, that is, in your case:

```
\documentclass[cm, reqno, 11pt, letterpaper]{amspset}
```

### EDIT

To solve the issue you mentioned in your comment.

Since the `fullpage` package accepts `cm` as an option, the document class passes this option to `fullpage`. This is the source of the problem.

So, use the following lines in your preamble:

```
\documentclass[cm, reqno, 11pt, letterpaper]{amspset}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[in]{fullpage}
```

so that `fullpage` is loaded with the default option `in` instead of `cm`.

Comment: The only problem I have with computer modern is that it completely gets rid of the margins for some reason, which makes it look unprofessional. If I could get this font without eliminating the margins, that would be great.

Comment: CM has nothing to do with the margins, please elaborate...

Comment: @EricAuld Does the edited contents in my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you so much! That really helps me. Looks great now.

Answer (score 1):

class option `cm` in that class gives the "standard" computer modern
fonts.

class option `palatino` tells the class to use the `mathpazo` package,
which also gives decent output (indeed, i prefer palatino to computer modern).

Comment: (Same comment as above) The only problem I have with computer modern is that it completely gets rid of the margins for some reason, which makes it look unprofessional. If I could get this font without eliminating the margins, that would be great.